# How to trigger SMS URI redirect in React-Native for multiple phone numbers?

Tags: ios, react-native, redirect, sms, uri

So basically I have a code which is already working for android devices, its purpose is to trigger the device's messaging/sms app with a pre-filled text in it. This also opens the iMessage app on iOS with the message already pre-filled successfully, but unfortunately it doesn't support multiple phone numbers.

The following code is currently an example on what I'm trying to do. The returned value from `generateURI()` is later used on react native's `Linking.openURL()` command.

```
export function generateURI(arrayOfPhoneNumbers, event) {
  var url = `sms:`

  for(var i = 0; i < arrayOfPhoneNumbers.length; i++) {
    url += `${arrayOfPhoneNumbers[i]},`
  }
  url = url.slice(0, -1); //remove last comma
  url += `${getSMSDivider()}body=Test Message`

  return url
}

function getSMSDivider() {
  return Platform.OS === "ios" ? "&" : "?";
}
```

**Things worth noting:**

Many URI Scheme patterns and standards don't seem to be respected by Apple as they are listed on the following link: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5724. For instance: every sms field should use the character `?`, but for iOS devices only `&` works, on top of that if you encode the string value passed as the `body=` attribute, android understands it fine, but iPhones don't. So unfortunately looking at a documented standard is not a viable solution when dealing with Apple's own rulebook.

Also Apple has a very strange statement saying `The URL string must not include any message text or other information.` on the following link https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/SMSLinks/SMSLinks.html
But that doesn't mean that they don't support multiple phone numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
let numbers = '';
contacts.forEach((phoneNumber: string) => {
  numbers += `${phoneNumber},`;
});
numbers = numbers.slice(0, -1);

const url = (Platform.OS === 'android')
  ? `sms:${numbers}?body=${text}`
  : `sms:/open?addresses=${numbers}&body=${text}`;
```

Comment: Hey @denisas, thanks for the solution! It worked good for me! Also without the `:/open?` part, using only the "addresses" attribute to keep track of the numbers :)